# Inequality $\left(1-\frac{x(1-x)+y(1-y)}{1-x+1-y}\right)^2+(1-\frac{x+y}{2})^2\geq (1-x)^2+(1-y)^2$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

it's a little problem found by myself

> let $x,y\neq 1$ .be real numbers then we have  :
>   $$\left(1-\frac{x(1-x)+y(1-y)}{1-x+1-y}\right)^2+\left(1-\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2\geq (1-x)^2+(1-y)^2$$

I tried Jensen's inequality and Am-Gm but without success .
I also tried Karamata's inequality but it fails.
I have a ugly proof using derivative  and it's too long to be explain here .

I'm looking for a contest proof .

Thanks a lot  to share your knowledge and your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x+y\neq2$ by AM-GM we obtain:$$\left(1-\frac{x(1-x)+y(1-y)}{1-x+1-y}\right)^2+\left(1-\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2=$$
$$=\left(\frac{(1-x)^2+(1-y)^2}{2-x-y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2-x-y}{2}\right)^2\geq$$
$$\geq2\sqrt{\left(\frac{(1-x)^2+(1-y)^2}{2-x-y}\right)^2\left(\frac{2-x-y}{2}\right)^2}= (1-x)^2+(1-y)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your inequality is equivalent to $$\frac{(x-y)^4}{4 (x+y-2)^2}$$